# Type Error :'stepUp' called on an object that does not implement interface HTMLInputElement

Tags: jquery

I have a "ApplyChanges" button, on click of this button I want to update value and am trying to save to database through controller, but I am getting the error: `Type Error: 'stepUp' called on an object that does not implement interface HTMLInputElement.`

Here is my code:

```
function ApplyChanges_Click()
{
    alert('Test');
    var moduleTitle = $("#moduleName").val();
    var cacheTimeout = $("#cacheTimeout").val();
    alert(cacheTimeout);
    var authorizedRoles = "";
    $('input[name="Roles"]:checked').each(function() {
        authorizedRoles = authorizedRoles + $(this).val() + ";";
    });
    alert(authorizedRoles);
    if ($('#showmobile').is(':checked')) {
        var showMobile = true;
    }
    alert(showMobile);
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/Admin/UpdateModuleSettings",
        dataType: "html",
        data: { 'moduleId': '@ViewBag.moduleId', 'moduleTitle':  moduleTitle, 'cacheTimeout': cacheTimeout, 'authorizedRoles': authorizedRoles, 'showmobile': showmobile, 'tabId': '@ViewBag.tabId' },
        success: function(response) {
            $("#LeftPane").html("");
            $("#RightPane").html("");
            $("#ContentPane").html(response);
        },
        error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) { }
    });
}
```

Comment: the error seems to be from the `data` you are passing to the ajax

Comment: Are all the elements you have used `val()` on Inputs? Please post *relevant* markup.

Comment: The relavent markup of one row ,like this i have 4 rows: <tr>
                        <td width="100" class="SubHead">
                            Module Name:
                        </td>
                        <td colspan="3">
                            &nbsp;
                            <input type="text" id="moduleName" width="300" class="NormalTextBox" value="@ViewBag.moduleTitle" />
                            @*@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ModuleName, new { id = "NormalTextBox", style = "width:300px;" })*@
                        </td>
                    </tr>

Answer (score 0):

Probably some variables of "data" option are empty:

- moduleTitle
- cacheTimeout
- authorizedRoles
- showmobile